# Obviously "wrong" classifications in test set using k-NN in R

Tags: r, classification, knn

I'm learning R. I'm using the k-NN method to classify an artificial dataset that I've created (two attributes and two classes). In my code, I print the training and the test sets, but the classes predicted for the test set in the last plot are not "in concordance" to the examples in the training set (that is, the class of the test examples (using 1-NN) is obviously wrong seeing the distribution of the training examples).

Could someone help me to identify the error in the code? Thank you very much.

The code is the following (run several times if necessary to see the wrong classification of the test set examples, due to the random generation of the training examples):

```
library(ElemStatLearn)
require(class)

c0 <- cbind(runif(50,0,5), runif(50,0,100))
c1 <- cbind(runif(50,5,10), runif(50,0,100))
training <- rbind(c0,c1)

classt <- vector()
classt[1:50] <- 0
classt[51:100] <- 1

x_ <- seq(0, 10, 1)
y_ <- seq(0, 10, 1)
testset <- matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 2)

for(i in x_){
  colaux <- cbind(rep(i,11), y_)
  testset <- rbind(testset, colaux)
}

testClass <- knn(train = training, test = testset, cl = classt, k = 1, prob = TRUE)

plot(training)
points(training, col=ifelse(classt==1, "coral", "cornflowerblue"))

plot(testset)
points(testset, col=ifelse(testClass==1, "coral", "cornflowerblue"))
```

Comment: I ran the code a few times, and am not seeing anything wrong with the output. Did you notice that the `y` scales are different in the two plots? If you're still convinced something is wrong, perhaps you could include the graphs and explain what exactly you think is wrong?

Comment: You are right, the problem is with the y scales of the plots. Sorry for the silly problem and thank you very much!

Comment: I've posted that as an answer. Feel free to accept it if you like.

Comment: you can use set.seed function to make your code reporoducible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classification is not "wrong". However, the graphs are confusing in that they're using different `y` scales. If you plot them on the same scales you'll see that the classifier is doing its job correctly.